# Creating new MySQL user... password and privileges not sticking

Tags: mysql

Connecting to MySQL through the command-line client as "root", I am trying to create a MySQL user with the following commands:

```
mysql> create user 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'mypass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on MY_DATABASE.* to 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'mypass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The user is created, but its password and privileges are not "sticking".  When I try to login using the password, I get an error:

```
~$ mysql -u myuser -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

However, I CAN login by simply pressing [enter] without a password:

```
~$ mysql -u myuser -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 95
Server version: 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Still, the user cannot see any tables... so not only did the password fail to persist, but the privileges that I set were lost too.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**  Posting contents from the mysql.user table, as requested in the comments:

```
mysql> select User, Host, Password from mysql.user;
+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User             | Host                | Password                                  |
+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | localhost           | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| root             | 127.0.0.1           | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| root             | ::1                 | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
|                  | localhost           |                                           |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost           | *817684763DD0B095B4703EC55053DAB57A2D9F4F |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost           | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
| myuser           | %                   | *C5250F20FB991AA969917726DE6547D425DB3234 |
+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of  `select User,Host,Password from mysql.user;` in your question.

Comment: Done... I've updated the question.

Comment: ok. see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an anonymose user for localhost and that anonymous user don't have any password.

> It is necessary to have both (`%` and `localhost`) accounts for your `myuser` to be
>   able to connect from anywhere as `myuser`. Without the localhost account,
>   the `anonymous user` account for `localhost` that is created by
>   `mysql_install_db` would take precedence when `myuser` connects from the
>   `localhost`. As a result, `myuser` would be treated as an `anonymous user`. The
>   reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more specific
>   Host column value than the `myuser'@'%'` account and thus comes earlier in
>   the user table sort order.

About sort order:

> The server uses sorting rules that order rows with the most-specific
>   Host values first. Literal host names and IP addresses are the most
>   specific. (The specificity of a literal IP address is not affected by
>   whether it has a netmask, so for example `192.168.1.13` and
>   `192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0` are considered equally specific.) The pattern `'%'` means `"any host"` and is least specific. The empty string
>   `''` also means `"any host"` but sorts after `'%'`. Rows with the same Host
>   value are ordered with the most-specific User values first (a blank
>   User value means `"any user"` and is least specific).

So `mysql` is considering your `myuser` as an `anonymous user` and since the `anonymous user` for `localhost` don't have any password, it is able to login without password.

To resolve your issue, you just need to create a `localhost` user for your `myuser`  with password